# Zsh Docker Plugin not Working

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I have been using oh-my-zsh for a while now and the docker plugin as recently stopped working for me for some reason.

I checked my ~/.zshrc file and the plugin is included

`plugins=(git colored-man colorize github jira vagrant virtualenv pip python brew osx zsh-syntax-highlighting docker)`

I checked the `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/docker` directory and there is a `_docker` file in there. Yet when I type `docker` and press Tab, I get none of the autocomplete shortcuts that I used to get.

I can confirm that my `git` plugin works just fine but not the `docker` plugin. Tried doing `exec zsh` and `source ~/.zshrc` and restarted my terminal but no luck.

Am I missing something?

Comment: In my case I was looking for docker-compose functions, I forgot that docker has separate plugins: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine.. Maybe it's not the case, but it may help somebody else

Answer (score -36, accepted):

I think you may be missing ,'s in between each plugin.

```
plugins=(git, colored-man, colorize, github, jira, vagrant, virtualenv, pip, python, brew, osx, zsh-syntax-highlighting, docker)
```

Alternatively you can place each plugin on a separate line:

```
plugins=(
  git
  colored-man
  colorize 
  github
  jira
  vagrant
  virtualenv
  pip
  python
  brew
  osx
  zsh-syntax-highlighting 
  docker
)
```

Comment: Adding commas results in error messages like "git, plugin not found."

Comment: This does not work and should not be marked as the answer

Comment: oh-my-zsh documentation clearly states that entries should be separated by whitespaces.

Answer (score 255):

You might want to try and remove any `.zcompdump-(...)` files you may have on your user's home directory - using something like `rm ~/.zcompdump*` on a terminal, or some file browser - and then reload the `.zshrc` file with the command `source ~/.zshrc` or restart the terminal - whichever works best for you. See [this](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/7642#issuecomment-471164659)

Then see if it works.

Comment: This worked for me too on Ubuntu Mate 18.04, zsh 5.4.2, mate-terminal 1.20.0. Had to delete `.zcompdump-<device-name>-5.4.2` and restart the terminal.

Comment: Worked for me on Mac OS Catalina

Comment: Worked on Fedora ! Thank you for this simple answer.

Comment: Had multiple .zcomp-dump* files in ~ and after deleting both docker autocomplete works perfectly. The solution has not generated any bugs on my system. Using OS X Catalina.

Comment: For those unaware, `source ~/.zshrc` also 'restarts'  your terminal. No need to actually close your terminal, or lose what you're in the middle of.

Comment: It works! But why? What is broken and how did that happen?

Comment: [1/2] @CorneliusRoemer The reason it works is because of how OMZ/ZSH plugins and autocomplete work. OMZ/ZSH uses .zcompdump as cache files for its shell completion system when you're typing, to make completion faster. These zcompdump files are compiled by OMZ/ZSH to map commands to functions it will run, many defined in plugins as well. So it runs through plugins folder and builds this cached file it uses while you type. When active plugin list changes in OMZ/ZSH config it does not automatically do what it should to rebuild this zcompdump cache file. By removing it you force it to be rebuilt.

Comment: [2/2] It's actually safe to delete them, since they will be recreated if not there, in your user home folder. Also, OMZ/ZSH uses the hostname as the suffix to each .zcompdump file. You can also browse through OMZ code at https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh to understand how the plugin system works.
Look at this file https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/oh-my-zsh.sh#L57-L71 and lines ~57 onwards to understand the usage of zcompdump files.

Answer (score 68):

It seems oh-my-zsh is not loading `plugins/docker/_docker` file. You should add it to `~/.zshrc` in an another way.
Add these lines to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
fpath+=($ZSH/plugins/docker)
autoload -U compinit && compinit
```

Comment: This just fixed it for me. Is this a known issue? (did not find it on the omz issue list).

Comment: Neither answer worked for me. I've opened a issue on GH https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/7687

Comment: I've been cracking my head the entire afternoon for this. Thanks, it solved the issue.

Comment: Confirmed, autocompletion started working for me after applying this to my `~/.zshrc` file, thanks!

Comment: Only `autoload -U compinit && compinit` was enough to get that working. I also moved the `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` to be executed before that. It's working now.

Comment: I had to change permissions with compaudit | xargs chmod g-w,o-w and then do this and it worked

Using Catalina

Comment: This makes the problem worse on WSL.

Answer (score 6):

For me it was simply the case that I needed to launch Docker for the first time from spotlight on my Mac in order for Docker for Desktop to get the access it needed. Then the `docker version` command worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps if you are using oh-my-zsh and autocomplete is not working:

1. Make the following three links:

   ```
   ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/docker.zsh-completion /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_docker
   ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/docker-machine.zsh-completion /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_docker-machine
   ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/docker-compose.zsh-completion /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_docker-compose
   ```
2. Either add `autoload -Uz compinit; compinit` to `.zshrc` or run in your shell:

   ```
   echo "autoload -Uz compinit; compinit" >> .zshrc
   ```

Answer (score 3):

In my case: **Windows 10 + WSL2 + Hyper**

I was having this error because I stopped Docker on Windows... Starting it again makes the error disappear in Hyper (thus, also in ZSH).

**No `.zshrc` changes or additional commands to add inside.**

Comment: Can you explain to me what your `Windows 10 + WSL2 + Hyper` looks like? A link to some docs online would be really helpful.

Comment: Sure, here are some links (sorry I can't find the original one I used before): https://blog.usejournal.com/how-i-turned-my-windows-pc-into-a-productivity-machine-for-development-wsl-hyper-oh-my-zsh-79ee614afbd2 // https://medium.com/@myrlandnu/guide-to-install-and-configure-hyper-for-windows-10-52a829c97b25

Answer (score 1):

@youhans's solution worked for me permanently. You might have permission issue to make needed adjustment on "zshrc". I have changed the permission to "read and write" and added the code snippet from @youhans's response to the end of "zshrc" file. Now completion system always works.

- Before I had to type below snippet in command line whenever open a new terminal.

  > autoload -Uz compinit && compinit

Answer (score 0):

In my case it occurred because of an alias. I had defined `alias docker=docker.exe`.
Removing that did it work again.

System & Environment

- O.S.: Windows 10 Home, x64
- Shell: Zsh (on Gitbash)

Answer (score 0):

For my case only was necessary the leave *git* plugin until the end instead,
originally my first attempt was:

```
plugins=(git kubectl kubectx)
```

When start to work was:

```
plugins=(z kubectl kubectx git)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the `docker` plugin's README, put `zstyle ':omz:plugins:docker' legacy-completion yes` in your `~/.zshrc`, yet make sure it is before `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`.