# Docker shell completion on OSX iTerm2 oh-my-zsh

Tags: docker, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to get Docker shell completion on this stack (OSX iTerm2 oh-my-zsh)

I followed this guide -> https://docs.docker.com/compose/completion/

First I executed this

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.zsh/completion
$ curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose/master/contrib/completion/zsh/_docker-compose > ~/.zsh/completion/_docker-compose
```

Then I added this two lines almost at the end `~/.zshrc` file

```
fpath=(~/.zsh/completion $fpath)
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -i
```

Then in the terminal I run

```
source ~/.zshrc
exec $SHELL -l
```

But when I press `tab` it suggest the files and folders on the path

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You set up the completion for `docker-compose` not for `docker`. If you would like add the `docker` completion too then run the following command and reload your shell.

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker-ce/master/components/cli/contrib/completion/zsh/_docker > ~/.zsh/completion/_docker
```

### Other solution (UPDATE):

Add the `docker` plugin to the `.zshrc`'s plugin list:

1. Open ~/.zshrc
2. Add `docker` to the plugins list like this:
   `plugins=(docker ...)`

Comment: I got mine to work fine using the guide linked https://docs.docker.com/compose/completion/#zsh and making sure `plugins=(docker,git ...)` and reloaded the shell and it works great using tab completion successfully.

Comment: It works but doesnt list the containers if you try to run docker exec -it

Comment: I tried everything and my Docker autocomplete wouldn't work on iterm2. This answer solved it for me, I hope it helps someone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45406609/2056484

Comment: @LucasBustamante It did help me! thank you! I notice that `compinit` should be at the end of config.

Comment: In MacOS Mojave adding `docker` into plugin list worked only after removing `.zcompdump*' files from the home directory (as suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55341741/1220546)

Comment: in my case i only added plugin docker after following on docker doc with my /opt/homebrew/autocompletions/_docker directly sylmink without ln into usr/local/share/zsh, thankyou ...

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you have the lastest version of `oh-my-zsh` by running: `upgrade_oh_my_zsh`

Also, it can't hurt to run [`rm ~/.zcompdump*`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/7642) after trying all the other answers.

Fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `vim ~/.zshrc` on your iTerm2
2. Find the line that contains plugins=() which normally will have git for example plugins=(git)
3. make a change by pressing I at that line ( i for Insert Mode)
4. change to `plugins=(docker git)` to add the docker extension and place ESC to exit insert mode
5. save by type `:w` to save and exit by type `:x`
6. restart your iTerm2 then docker completion should work now

Answer (score 0):

Docker has updated their docs with the answer on how to do this after you have installed `Docker Desktop`: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/macfaqs/#how-do-i-install-shell-completion